# Loopback - Link related model with code

Tags: node.js, relationship, loopbackjs

I'm loading some sample data to help me test in my development cycle. Some models are related, so I'd like to add them like that.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to link two models with code. This is what I have so far:

```
app.models.Region.count({}).then(function (count) {
    if (count > 0) throw "There are regions already";

    return app.models.Region.create({
      "type": "Europe"
    });
  }).then(function (region) {
    console.log("Region created", region);

    return app.models.Country.count({}).then(function (count) {
      if (count > 0) throw "There are countries already";

      return app.models.Country.create({
        "countryCode": "es",
        "regions": [region]
      });
    }).then(function (country) {
      console.log("Country created", country.regions);
      //country.regions = region
      //country.save();
    })
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

My Country model has this relation:

```
"regions": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Region",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
```

Comment: Did you try calling .create() method on relation: `country.regions.create(region)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to create the region after you've created the Country or switch the order of the creates.

Here's creating the Region after the Country.

```
app.models.Region.count({}).then(function (count) {
    if (count > 0) throw "There are regions already";

    return app.models.Region.create({
      "type": "Europe"
    });
  }).then(function (region) {
    console.log("Region created", region);

    return app.models.Country.count({}).then(function (count) {
      if (count > 0) throw "There are countries already";

      return app.models.Country.create({
        "countryCode": "es"
      });
    }).then(function (country) {
      // use this extra line
      return country.regions.create(region);
    }).then(function (country) {
      console.log("Country created", country.regions);
      //country.regions = region
      //country.save();
    })
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

And here's how you could swap the order of your creates so you start from the other way around.

```
return app.models.Country.count({}).then(function (count) {
  if (count > 0) throw "There are countries already";

  return app.models.Country.create({
    "countryCode": "es"
  });

}).then(function (country) {
  console.log("Country created", country);

  return app.models.Region.count({}).then(function (count) {
    if (count > 0) throw "There are regions already";

    return country.regions.create({
      "type": "Europe"
    });
  }).then(function (region) {
    console.log("Region created", region);
    console.log("Country has regions", country.regions);

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

})
```

And just to note that if this is all for test data then you should really look into loopback-testing, see the section on [building test data](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-testing/#building-test-data)

Comment: I finally did it creating the Country before the Region. I don't see how you link Countries and Regions in your answer. What I did, was setting the "countryId" property of the region to the country's Id. Fix that in your answer so I can mark it as solved ;)

Comment: Strange, you shouldn't need to set `countryId` when creating the region with `country.regions.create` as it automatically creates the relationship upon creating the object.